# Using @selector in RubyMotion

Tags: objective-c, syntax, rubymotion

How do I translate the following method call from ObjectiveC to RubyMotion syntax:

```
[self.faceView addGestureRecognizer:[
    [UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.faceView
    action:@selector(pinch:)]];
```

I got this far:

```
self.faceView.addGestureRecognizer(
  UIPinchGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(
  self.faceView, action:???))
```

I understand the `@selector(pinch:)` indicates a delegation to the receiver object `pinch` method, but how would I do this in RubyMotion? Maybe using a block?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to just use a string to specify the selector:

```
self.faceView.addGestureRecognizer(
  UIPinchGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(
  self.faceView, action:'pinch'))
```

Comment: The introductory video at Pragmatic Studios covers this, and shows a couple good examples of migrating Obj-C code to ruby: http://pragmaticstudio.com/screencasts/rubymotion

Comment: I'm guessing your pinch action will actually look like this: 'def pinch(recognizer)' which means your selector will actually be 'pinch:'

Comment: As @JacoPretorius points out, if the target method takes an argument, your selector string must end with a colon `("pinch:")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@gesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self.faceView,action:'pinch:')

self.faceView.addGestureRecognizer(@gesture)

def pinch(foo)

end
```

If you don't want the method handler to take an argument, use `action:'pinch'` instead. It will then look for a method like this:

```
def pinch

end
```

Using an instance var (`@gesture = ...`) is a good idea here because sometimes gesture recognizers and the GC don't play well together if you don't make the gesture var an instance var of a UIViewController. (In my experience)